# How to write multiline quotes in an answer

Tags: feature-request, support, blockquote, linebreak

While answering questions, I found that the delimiter '>' for blockquotes on answers truncates newlines.

Refer to the following example.

> I have typed one line here.
> This is has been typed on the next line

As you can see, the two separate lines have been stacked on one.

However, at times I like to make multiline quotes. Thanks to my background in CS, I achieve it using `<br>` tags, like so -

> This is the first line
>
>  This has been typed on the next line.

My question is, is there an easier way to write multiline comments, as typing `<br>` in front of each line is cumbersome? Besides, it is not at all intuitive, and people without a technical background may not know how to achieve said result.

If it isn't possible, it is my humble request to change the way quotations work making it more intuitive to include multiline quotations.

Comment: Same way you split up lines in markdown generally: put a blank line in between (either with a > or without, depending on the effect you want).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately that's how Markdown is designed.

Just like emails where *every* line of quoted content begins with a `>`, you *should* add a leading `>` for every line of `<blockquote>`

Markdown supports line breaks using two trailing spaces, so you could write this (`$` is a visual indicator of a line end):

```markdown
> Content  $
> Content on new line$
```

Result:

> Content
> Content on new line

Note, though, it's uncommon for a required line break instead of starting a new paragraph for readability. Generally you should write this instead:

```markdown
> Content
>
> More content
```

Comment: additional lines leads to nasty gaps in the rendered text though, IMO

Answer (score 7):

This is not exclusive to blockquotes; text on a new line is *always* appended to the previous line.

Here is an example.
This is written as a second line but appears on the same line as the first.

Using `<br>` works, but you can also append two spaces, as mentioned in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting):

> Here is an example.
> This is written as a second line and appears like that as well.